# Pytorch RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory with a huge amount of free memory

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

While training the model, I encountered the following problem:

`RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 304.00 MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 142.76 MiB already allocated; 6.32 GiB free; 158.00 MiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF`

As we can see, the error occurs when trying to allocate 304 MiB of memory, while 6.32 GiB is free! What is the problem? As I can see, the suggested option is to set max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation. Will it help and how to do it correctly?

This is my version of PyTorch:

torch==1.10.2+cu113

torchvision==0.11.3+cu113

torchaudio===0.10.2+cu113

Comment: Had a similar issue in colab. Solved by reducing per_device_train_batch_size to 8 instead of 64 inside TrainingArguments

Comment: torch==1.8.1 may also improve the issue

Comment: Why is this even a problem? I tried to create a 512x512 image, but 8GB video RAM not sufficient - what kind of crappy Python implementation is that?

Answer (score 11):

I wasted several hours until I discovered that reducing the `batch size` and resizing the width of my input image (`image size`) were necessary steps.

Comment: I've tried reducing the image and batch sizes to very small values. Now the memory required for allocation is only 30Mb. However, I'm still getting the same issue... any ideas? -- RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 30.00 MiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 5.16 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 5.30 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

Comment: YOu need a nvidia GPU >2gb

Comment: I have a 6Gb worth of GPU memory but it isn't being allocated. How do I get this allocated?

Comment: What Script to you use? Github repository ?

Comment: i'm trying this setup. (https://rentry.org/SDInstallation)

Comment: try decrease "ddim_steps", or other parameters. Read 7. Common Errors/Tips. If nothing works, use CPU.

Comment: Maybe you could also try tuning `max_split_size_mb` as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73809045/6655150

Comment: this is not a solution because it is a trade-off between model performance and GPU memory

Answer (score 3):

Your problem may be due to fragmentation of your GPU memory.You may want to empty your cached memory used by caching allocator.

```
import torch
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I called this method before training the model and got the same error.

Comment: Can you try to decrease the batch size? And make sure you restart before running again.

Comment: where do you put that command? Is it in the launch.py file?

Comment: According to [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/keep-getting-cuda-oom-error-with-pytorch-failing-to-allocate-all-free-memory/133896/14), we shouldn't use `empty_cache()`.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying this command:

```
python3 val.py --weights ./weights/yolov5l-xs-1.pt --img 1996 --data ./data/VisDrone.yaml
```

and I have a 24G Titan video Card.

Then I reduced the image size and worked for me. to:

```
python3 val.py --weights ./weights/yolov5l-xs-1.pt --img 1280  --data ./data/VisDrone.yaml
```

Results:

```
Class     Images     Labels          P          R     mAP@.5 mAP@.5:.95: 100%|████████████████████████████████| 18/18 [00:50<00:00,  2.79s/it]
                 all        548      38759      0.653      0.537      0.584      0.375
          pedestrian        548       8844       0.74      0.631      0.708      0.375
              people        548       5125      0.677      0.506      0.574      0.258
             bicycle        548       1287      0.541      0.377       0.41      0.213
                 car        548      14064      0.828      0.868      0.904      0.681
                 van        548       1975      0.636      0.566      0.601      0.453
               truck        548        750      0.595      0.516      0.538      0.388
            tricycle        548       1045      0.601      0.416      0.457      0.288
     awning-tricycle        548        532      0.387      0.242      0.245      0.173
                 bus        548        251      0.782      0.653      0.725      0.565
               motor        548       4886      0.744      0.598      0.674      0.355
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_size = (512, 512)  # Set the desired width and height

# Resize the image
resized_image = image.resize(new_size)
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about Python, especially where I could set the env variables, but I read this [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#cuda-memory-management),thought I understood that no block size is set for the purpose of fast memory synchronization  and put the following line in the automatic 1111 folder in the **empty-cache.py** file hoped that's right place to do so,and that solved my problems.

```
 PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=max_split_size_mb:256
```

Answer (score -7):

It works for me with this:

```
pip install accelerate
```

Comment: Well, that import alone is very unlikely to be of any help whatsoever.