# RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. How can I set max_split_size_mb?

Tags: memory, pytorch, runtime-error, google-colaboratory

I found this problem running a neural network on Colab Pro+ (with the high RAM option).

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 8.00 GiB (GPU 0;
> 15.90 GiB total capacity; 12.04 GiB already allocated; 2.72 GiB free; 12.27 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.
> See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

I have already decreased the batch size to 2. I upload the data using the `h5py` format.

At this point, I assume the only thing I can try is setting the `max_split_size_mb`.

I could not find anything about how I can implement the `max_split_size_mb`. The [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html) was not clear to me.

Comment: So what was a solution? I am having the same issue. I do not chunk the payload. Do I nee to?

Answer (score 56):

The `max_split_size_mb` configuration value can be set as an environment variable.

The exact syntax [is documented](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#memory-management), but in short:

> The behavior of caching allocator can be controlled via environment variable `PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF`. The format is `PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=<option>:<value>,<option2>:<value2>`…
>
> Available options:
>
> …
>
> - `max_split_size_mb` prevents the allocator from splitting blocks larger than this size (in MB). This can help prevent fragmentation and may allow some borderline workloads to complete without running out of memory. Performance cost can range from ‘zero’ to ‘substantial’ depending on allocation patterns. Default value is unlimited, i.e. all blocks can be split. The `memory_stats()` and `memory_summary()` methods are useful for tuning. This option should be used as a last resort for a workload that is aborting due to ‘out of memory’ and showing a large amount of inactive split blocks.
>
> …

So, you should be able to set an environment variable in a manner similar to the following:

Windows: `set 'PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=max_split_size_mb:512'`

Linux: `export 'PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=max_split_size_mb:512'`

This will depend on what OS you're using - in your case, for Google Colab, you might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306150/setting-environment-variables-in-google-colab) helpful.

Comment: I played with several values for the `mb` size but couldn't get it to work (I have an old 1080ti), but passing in this option did the trick: `--n_samples 1`

Comment: Being curious, what's the default value of this option?

Comment: @zenw0lf Passing in `--n_samples 1` to what?

Comment: @Zorgoth To the command that you run that throws the OOM exception. In my case was to the Stable Diffusion command as seen here: https://github.com/CompVis/stable-diffusion

Comment: For me on Manjaro Linux with an older NVIDIA GPU, it works wonderfully :). But I had to learn that I have to insert it into my ~/.bashrc to make it work after a reboot.

Comment: @zenw0lf As @Zorgoth I also want to know `--n_samples 1` to what. You say, the command that throws the OOM, so the python program that runs? What if this does not support that argument? I am sorry but I don't understand what you meant by that

Answer (score 28):

Adding to the other answer, the size to be used really depends on the numbers in the error message, but if you're running Python,

```py
import os

os.environ["PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF"] = "max_split_size_mb:<enter-size-here>"
```

at the start of the script has been found to work sometimes for me. Try different sizes.

Comment: Be careful with this. At least if you spread tensors across GPUs, PyTorch seems to ask you to set the environment variable from the command line, you cannot set it with Python code, see [RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. How can I set max_split_size_mb?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77856985/11154841) as a code proof.

Answer (score 3):

Another option to try:

```
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

if you want to empty the cache allocated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using [Stable Diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_Diffusion) with a [GTX 1660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_16_series#Desktop) or other [16XX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_16_series) 6 GB card, this option is [not actually required](https://www.andreszsogon.com/fix-stable-difussion-automatic1111-webui-on-geforce-gtx-16xx/) when using the latest Nvidia drivers.

When using version 531, which makes Stable Diffusion much faster, `--medvram` will be required, though.